# Metadata Refinement SharePoint 2013 - AND type Query (possible?)

Tags: search-results

I've got a search results webpart set-up which returns items from a large document library. Alongside it is a refiner web part which refines the results based on a managed metadata field set on those items (each document is tagged with multiple metadata values). Selecting multiple refiners would result in an OR-type query, returning all results tagged with either of the values. But I would like to have results based on a AND-type query. Is this possible? and if yes, how?

Comment: I'm working on this as well.

Comment: That would be multiple values selected for the same managed property, right? As far as I know selecting a value for different properties will be an "AND" operator

Comment: Thank you @KasperBoLarsen for your comment. I don't fully understand your recommendation. Could you please give more details? Thanks!